# Symofny2 Query builder leftJoin with condition from Many relationship

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder

I have a product that has descriptions, names and etc in multiple languages saved in another table. One product can have multiple translations(product data).

Currently i get all the translations of the product and do a foreach and ifs to get the needed translation based on locale... If there are many languages the cycle becomes large and ugly...

I want to get only the needed translation data from the query, based on locale. I am doing this query but it does not work:

```
    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->select([
            'p',
            'pt',
            'lang',
        ])
        ->leftJoin('p.translations', 'pt', 'with', 'pt.language.iso = :locale')
        ->leftJoin('pt.language', 'lang')
        ->where("p.status = 1")
        ->SetParameter('locale', $locale)
        ->add('orderBy','p.position ASC');
return $query->getQuery()->getResult();
```

This is one of the options i tried and I think this is the closest i get to the solution, but i get error:

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 281 near 'iso = :locale': Error: Class Mp\ShopBundle\Entity\ProductLanguageData has no field or association named language.iso
```

The error says it all, but i cant understand how to fix this. Any help would be apreciated.

Comment: first, you should select products and join the translations instead of leftjoin. LeftJoin will deliver products even if the have no translation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how your columns exactly looks like, but you have a table with languages contains the column "iso" and you have the table product_translation must contains something like "language_id" and "product_id", right? Then your query can looks like:

```
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->select([
            'p',
            'pt',
            'lang',
        ])
        ->join('language', 'lang', 'with', 'l.iso = :locale')
        ->join('product_translations', 'pt', 'with', 'pt.language_id = l.id and p.id = pt.product_id')
        ->where("p.status = 1")
        ->SetParameter('locale', $locale)
        ->add('orderBy','p.position ASC');
```

You should create two custom joins. Join the language with iso column first, then the translation table. And you need to bind the product table with the translation table, here you need a link to languages and products.